# neo4j: PathExpender versus RelationshipExpender

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-embedded

Concerning "PathExpender versus RelationshipExpender" all I could find was this:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html#_pathexpander_relationshipexpander

Does this mean, that the RelationshipExpender is deprecated?

In case it is not deprecated, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `RelationshipExpander` is deprecated.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/RelationshipExpander.html